# DATETIME column in SQL SELECT WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL table where there is a column (datetime, null) which contains values such as

```
2014-10-22 16:10:23.797
2014-10-22 16:10:23.817
2014-10-22 16:10:23.850
2014-10-22 16:10:23.880
2014-10-22 16:10:23.900
2014-10-22 16:10:23.923
2014-10-22 16:10:23.950
2014-10-22 16:10:23.973
2014-10-22 16:10:23.997
2014-10-22 16:10:24.023
```

How do I write a `SELECT` statement to only select the rows where the HH:MM:SS equals 16:10:23? (ie: exclude the bottom row in my example)

I've tried

```
WHERE col1 = '22/10/2014 16:10:23'

WHERE col1 like '2014-10-22 16:10:23%'
```

all with no luck

Comment: not a duplicate IMHO as my question pertains to a WHERE clause, not the formatting of a column in a result set. A slight difference i think (happy to be shot down though)

Comment: If you know how to truncate the millis you know how to build the `WHERE`.

Comment: `...WHERE DATEADD(millisecond, -datepart(millisecond, col1), col1)='22/10/2014 16:10:23'`

Comment: @TimSchmelter - is that the best approach? Would `WHERE col1 >= '2014-10-22 16:10:23' and col1 < '2014-10-22 16:10:24'` allow better use of indexes?

Comment: @petelids: you have to measure it, maybe. But perhaps it's not a static value but is another column.

Comment: Where  col1 Between dateadd(MILLISECOND,-datepart(MILLISECOND,convert(datetime,'12/20/2015 11:45:31.393',102)),'12/20/2015 11:45:31.393')
AND
dateadd(MILLISECOND,-1 ,dateadd(SS,1,convert(datetime,'12/20/2015 11:45:31.393',102)))